# Issue with tracing signals in SystemC-AMS

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, systemc

I implemented a sine-wave-generator in SystemC-AMS and want to visualize its output over a certain time period. For this I want to create a vcd file. The code of the generator and the main-function are shown below. I have the problem that the vcd file is empty. What am I doing wrong?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "systemc.h"
#include "systemc-ams.h"
#include "sin_source.h"

int sc_main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    sca_tdf::sca_signal <double> out1;
    sin_source mySine("sine1");
    mySine.out(out1);

    sca_util::sca_trace_file *tf1= sca_util::sca_create_vcd_trace_file("sine_wave");
    sca_util::sca_trace(tf1, out1, "i'm_sine_1");

    sc_core::sc_start(10, sc_core::SC_MS);
    sca_util::sca_close_vcd_trace_file(tf1);

    return 0;
}
```

sin_source.h:

```
#include <systemc-ams.h>

SCA_TDF_MODULE(sin_source)
{
    sca_tdf::sca_out<double> out;

    double ampl;
    double freq;

    void set_attributes()
    {
        out.set_timestep(5, SC_US);
    }

    void processing ()
    {
        double t=out.get_time().to_seconds();
        double x = ampl * std::sin(2.0 * M_PI * freq * t);
        out.write(x);
    }

    SCA_CTOR(sin_source):
        out("out"), ampl(1.0), freq(1e3){}
};
```

EDIT: Unfortunately renaming the signal did not show any improvement. I now changed the main.cpp as shown below. In the output, the last "Hello World" message I see is the one with number 4. So probably my simulation is never started before the program exits.

Changed main.cpp:

```
int sc_main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    sca_tdf::sca_signal <double> out1;
    sin_source mySine("sine1");
    mySine.out(out1);

    std::cout << "Hello World 2" << std::endl;

    sca_util::sca_trace_file *tf1= sca_util::sca_create_vcd_trace_file("sine_wave");

    std::cout << "Hello World 3" << std::endl;

    sca_util::sca_trace(tf1, out1, "sine");

    std::cout << "Hello World 4" << std::endl;

    sc_core::sc_start(10, sc_core::SC_MS);

    std::cout << "Hello World 5" << std::endl;

    sca_util::sca_close_vcd_trace_file(tf1);

    std::cout << "Hello World 6" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
Hello World
Hello World 2
        SystemC 2.3.2-Accellera --- Jul 17 2018 16:06:04
        Copyright (c) 1996-2017 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED


        SystemC AMS extensions 2.1.0-COSEDA Release date: 20160404
        Copyright (c) 2010-2014  by Fraunhofer-Gesellschaft IIS/EAS
        Copyright (c) 2015-2016  by COSEDA Technologies GmbH
        Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0


Hello World 3
Hello World 4

Info: SystemC-AMS: 
    1 SystemC-AMS modules instantiated
    1 SystemC-AMS views created
    1 SystemC-AMS synchronization objects/solvers instantiated


Info: SystemC-AMS: 
    1 dataflow clusters instantiated
      cluster 0:
        1 dataflow modules/solver, contains e.g. module: sine1
        1 elements in schedule list,  
        5 us cluster period, 
        ratio to lowest:  1              e.g. module: sine1
        ratio to highest: 1 sample time  e.g. module: sine1
        0 connections to SystemC de, 0 connections from SystemC de
```

Comment: Probably you can try to ask on systemc ams forum http://forums.accellera.org/forum/13-systemc-ams-analogmixed-signal/

Comment: A shot in the dark: try renaming your signal to something that doesn't use any special characters (ie., remove the apostrophe from [i'm_sine_1]). I've seen several EDA tools that are unable to deal with similar things.

Comment: Renaming the signal didn't work @rainer . Please have a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue. Do you opened the file in a texteditor to check whether it's really empty?

The may problematic issue, I see is the ' in the name of the signal (sca_util::sca_trace(tf1, out1, "i'm_sine_1");) - may your waveviewer don't like it.

Comment: So my code above produces a sine-wave plot for you? Do you use an eclipse/cygwin setup?